# Practical Actionscript/Flash AS3 code to crash decompilers

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, crash, decompiler

Does anyone have any practical examples of code that crashes `flash decompilers`?

I appreciate that many so called `swf` encryption/protections systems exist that use both `preloaders` and have mechanism to crash common `decompilers`, but I cant use any of these as non support Air packaged apps without breaking parts of the app.

I appreciate that crashing the `decompiler` only slows someone down, so its part of other mechanisms.

Comment: Have you tried using a fuzzer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If examples of code that crash decompilers existed, it'd be easy for a decompiler to target the bytecode that generate the error and fix it.

The best you can do is use obfuscators. Don't waste your time trying to do something that is a) nearly impossible b) easily circumvented if it existed. That's snake oil.